# How do I pull an integer out of a DataFrame to use in DataFrame.rolling()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Excerpt from DataFrame for reference.

| index | date | spx | window |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15076 | 2021-08-09 | 4432.340000 | 100 |
| 15077 | 2021-08-10 | 4436.740000 | 105 |
| 15078 | 2021-08-11 | 4447.690000 | 90 |
| 15079 | 2021-08-12 | 4460.820000 | 120 |
| 15080 | 2021-08-13 | 4467.990000 | 80 |

I'm trying to add a column to my DataFrame that displays the moving average of the 'spx' column with a window size corresponding to the value in the 'window' column. My little brain came up with this...

```
df['sma'] = df['spx'].rolling(df['window']).mean()
```

This does not work of course, because the rolling() function is looking for an integer for the window argument, not a DataFrame.

For example, for row 15079, I would like the new 'moving_average' column to show the moving average of the 'spx' series with a window of 120.

For row 15080, I'd like the new 'moving_average' column to show the moving average of 'spx' with a window of 80. Effectively, this would be...

```
df['sma'] = df['spx'].rolling(80).mean()
```

However, I don't know how to pluck the integer value from the window column to pass to the rolling() function.

Comment: what's the expected output look like? you want a rolling average using two columns? it's not clear what you want.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for taking a look. I edited my original post for clarity. I tried to generalize the issue a bit, which will hopefully make the request more clearn.

Comment: Yes I saw this question posted earlier and it was unclear. It would be easier if you selected a smaller rolling window, so that we can reproduce output. When there are only 5 rows but the window is 80 or 100, you cannot reproduce the output, so maybe have smaller numbers for the window. and your desired output based off those numbers.

Comment: I don't think you are looking for a rolling average here, in the truest sense. You just want the average of df['spx'] for x rows from the current row depending depending on window. try slicing df[current row index + x['window]]['spx'].mean() or something like that. I think you may be overcomplicating it trying to use a rolling average function. You may have to use a lambda function to apply to each row.

Comment: another longer method, which may not be useful is to just create a new column for each unique value of df[window]. If there's only a few values you'd have a consistent rolling window in each new column and then you can perform operations from there.

Answer (score 0):

This will be incredibly slow and I advise not using it. If you have the necessary memory and can limit the number of different rolling columns just create all of them if you want maybe one by one and use them but this should be a slow solution for what you want.

```
df['sma'] = df.apply(lambda x: df.loc[x.name-x['window']:x.name]['spx'].mean(), axis=1)
```